# How to substitute gender pronouns in a large corpus of text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am writing a novel and half-way through it I decided to change an important protagonist from male to female. I wrote some simple Python code thinking I could change the pronouns for that particular character easily, but it changed the pronouns of *all* the characters accidentally. Here's some example text from the novel:

```
example_text = "John walked to the market. He was tired, but decided to leg it anyway, he needed the exercise! He met Joe along the way. Joe was a tall man and walked fast, during his heyday, he was an impressive athlete."
```

I wished to change Joe (male) to Jane (female) and wrote the following simple code:

```
example_text = example_text.replace(" he ", " she ")
example_text = example_text.replace(" He ", " She ")
example_text = example_text.replace(" his ", " her ")
example_text = example_text.replace(" man ", " woman ")
example_text = example_text.replace("Joe", "Jane")
```

But the above code changes the pronouns for both Joe and John to female. I now realize that I'll have to use NLP to do this, but is there a module or an algorithm to do this?

Comment: Pronoun resolution is one of the biggest problems in NLP...

Comment: you might just consider doing it manually

Comment: @BrianJoseph really brings to mind the following comic: https://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: As @BrianJoseph said: This is quite tricky. Maybe you can rather replace pronouns by a marker and then go through them manually. But things like "he was a good father" or other references to male vs female roles (which you cannot possibly all list) will probably make it impossible to not go through it at least once by hand.

Comment: Yeah you can not do this with 100% accuracy. You can look into state of the art, https://huggingface.co/coref/ , but it’s not gonna be as accurate as doing it manually